# A better way to update form components visibility from a spin button?

Tags: vba, forms, excel

I am wondering if someone may be able to shed some light on a more streamline way of doing the below?

Basically when the Spin button changes it will jump to the label and update what lines are visible the code works just fine but I was wondering if there is a less bulky way of coding this into the form?

```
    Private Sub Meds_Change()
    meds_txt.Text = Meds.value
End Sub


Private Sub meds_txt_Change()
    If meds_txt.value > 1 Then
        If meds_txt.value = 2 Then GoTo ShowTwo
        If meds_txt.value = 3 Then GoTo ShowThree
        If meds_txt.value = 4 Then GoTo ShowFour
        If meds_txt.value = 5 Then GoTo ShowFive
        If meds_txt.value = 6 Then GoTo ShowSix
        If meds_txt.value = 7 Then GoTo ShowSeven
    Else: GoTo ShowOne
    End If


Exit Sub

ShowOne:

    labelTwo.Visible = False: MNameTwo.Visible = False
    MDoseTwo.Visible = False: MFrequencyTwo.Visible = False
    labelThree.Visible = False: MNameThree.Visible = False
    MDoseThree.Visible = False: MFrequencyThree.Visible = False
    labelFour.Visible = False: MNameFour.Visible = False
    MDoseFour.Visible = False: MFrequencyFour.Visible = False
    labelFive.Visible = False: MNameFive.Visible = False
    MDoseFive.Visible = False: MFrequencyFive.Visible = False
    labelSix.Visible = False: MNameSix.Visible = False
    MDoseSix.Visible = False: MFrequencySix.Visible = False
    labelSeven.Visible = False: MNameSeven.Visible = False
    MDoseSeven.Visible = False: MFrequencySeven.Visible = False
    GoTo Finish
ShowTwo:
    labelTwo.Visible = True: MNameTwo.Visible = True
    MDoseTwo.Visible = True: MFrequencyTwo.Visible = True
    labelThree.Visible = False: MNameThree.Visible = False
    MDoseThree.Visible = False: MFrequencyThree.Visible = False
    labelFour.Visible = False: MNameFour.Visible = False
    MDoseFour.Visible = False: MFrequencyFour.Visible = False
    labelFive.Visible = False: MNameFive.Visible = False
    MDoseFive.Visible = False: MFrequencyFive.Visible = False
    labelSix.Visible = False: MNameSix.Visible = False
    MDoseSix.Visible = False: MFrequencySix.Visible = False
    labelSeven.Visible = False: MNameSeven.Visible = False
    MDoseSeven.Visible = False: MFrequencySeven.Visible = False
    GoTo Finish
ShowThree:
    labelTwo.Visible = True: MNameTwo.Visible = True
    MDoseTwo.Visible = True: MFrequencyTwo.Visible = True
    labelThree.Visible = True: MNameThree.Visible = True
    MDoseThree.Visible = True: MFrequencyThree.Visible = True
    labelFour.Visible = False: MNameFour.Visible = False
    MDoseFour.Visible = False: MFrequencyFour.Visible = False
    labelFive.Visible = False: MNameFive.Visible = False
    MDoseFive.Visible = False: MFrequencyFive.Visible = False
    labelSix.Visible = False: MNameSix.Visible = False
    MDoseSix.Visible = False: MFrequencySix.Visible = False
    labelSeven.Visible = False: MNameSeven.Visible = False
    MDoseSeven.Visible = False: MFrequencySeven.Visible = False
    GoTo Finish
ShowFour:
    labelTwo.Visible = True: MNameTwo.Visible = True
    MDoseTwo.Visible = True: MFrequencyTwo.Visible = True
    labelThree.Visible = True: MNameThree.Visible = True
    MDoseThree.Visible = True: MFrequencyThree.Visible = True
    labelFour.Visible = True: MNameFour.Visible = True
    MDoseFour.Visible = True: MFrequencyFour.Visible = True
    labelFive.Visible = False: MNameFive.Visible = False
    MDoseFive.Visible = False: MFrequencyFive.Visible = False
    labelSix.Visible = False: MNameSix.Visible = False
    MDoseSix.Visible = False: MFrequencySix.Visible = False
    labelSeven.Visible = False: MNameSeven.Visible = False
    MDoseSeven.Visible = False: MFrequencySeven.Visible = False
    GoTo Finish
ShowFive:
    labelTwo.Visible = True: MNameTwo.Visible = True
    MDoseTwo.Visible = True: MFrequencyTwo.Visible = True
    labelThree.Visible = True: MNameThree.Visible = True
    MDoseThree.Visible = True: MFrequencyThree.Visible = True
    labelFour.Visible = True: MNameFour.Visible = True
    MDoseFour.Visible = True: MFrequencyFour.Visible = True
    labelFive.Visible = True: MNameFive.Visible = True
    MDoseFive.Visible = True: MFrequencyFive.Visible = True
    labelSix.Visible = False: MNameSix.Visible = False
    MDoseSix.Visible = False: MFrequencySix.Visible = False
    labelSeven.Visible = False: MNameSeven.Visible = False
    MDoseSeven.Visible = False: MFrequencySeven.Visible = False
    GoTo Finish
ShowSix:
    labelTwo.Visible = True: MNameTwo.Visible = True
    MDoseTwo.Visible = True: MFrequencyTwo.Visible = True
    labelThree.Visible = True: MNameThree.Visible = True
    MDoseThree.Visible = True: MFrequencyThree.Visible = True
    labelFour.Visible = True: MNameFour.Visible = True
    MDoseFour.Visible = True: MFrequencyFour.Visible = True
    labelFive.Visible = True: MNameFive.Visible = True
    MDoseFive.Visible = True: MFrequencyFive.Visible = True
    labelSix.Visible = True: MNameSix.Visible = True
    MDoseSix.Visible = True: MFrequencySix.Visible = True
    labelSeven.Visible = False: MNameSeven.Visible = False
    MDoseSeven.Visible = False: MFrequencySeven.Visible = False
    GoTo Finish
ShowSeven:
    labelTwo.Visible = True: MNameTwo.Visible = True
    MDoseTwo.Visible = True: MFrequencyTwo.Visible = True
    labelThree.Visible = True: MNameThree.Visible = True
    MDoseThree.Visible = True: MFrequencyThree.Visible = True
    labelFour.Visible = True: MNameFour.Visible = True
    MDoseFour.Visible = True: MFrequencyFour.Visible = True
    labelFive.Visible = True: MNameFive.Visible = True
    MDoseFive.Visible = True: MFrequencyFive.Visible = True
    labelSix.Visible = True: MNameSix.Visible = True
    MDoseSix.Visible = True: MFrequencySix.Visible = True
    labelSeven.Visible = True: MNameSeven.Visible = True
    MDoseSeven.Visible = True: MFrequencySeven.Visible = True
    GoTo Finish

Finish:
End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: This is a question for https://codereview.stackexchange.com.

Comment: For the sake of the art: Just added a more general approach where you **need not to multiply** the number of arrays for each column/control type and can even stick to your naming convention using "One", "Two" etc. (e.g. LabelOne, labelTwo ..).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Conceptually, I would load all controls into 1-dimensional arrays and make them visible in a loop ... like so (this is in the code space of your form):

```
Dim MyCtls(6) As Control

Private Sub SpinButton1_Change()
    ' let the index not go outside the array dimension
    If Me.SpinButton1 < 1 Then Me.SpinButton1 = 1
    If Me.SpinButton1 > 7 Then Me.SpinButton1 = 7

    Me.SpinText = Me.SpinButton1
End Sub

Private Sub SpinText_Change()
Dim Idx As Integer

    For Idx = 1 To 7
        ' controls with indices <= spinbutton value are visible, higher ones are dark
        If Idx <= Me.SpinText Then
            MyCtls(Idx - 1).Visible = True
        Else
            MyCtls(Idx - 1).Visible = False
        End If
    Next Idx

End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
Dim Idx As Integer

    ' load TB1..7 controls into array (index 0-6)
    For Idx = 1 To 7
        Set MyCtls(Idx - 1) = Me.Controls("TB" & Idx)
    Next Idx
End Sub
```

There are 7 text boxes `TB1` to `TB7` which are loaded into a 1-dimensional array ... you can use 4 arrays - 1 per field type ... it's important that the names can be somehow constructed by the loop counter `Idx` ... the rest should be self explanatory.

Comment: That's Brilliant, thanks. I had never touched on Controls in this manner before. I will get all of this implemented now. Thanks so much for your help!

Comment: Appreciate your straight ahead code. (Added an alternative just to show a more general approach with less arrays :-)

Answer (score 1):

**More general alternative with less arrays**

Just to show you a *more general approach* where you **need not** to *multiply* the *number of arrays* for each column/control type and can even stick to your naming convention using "One", "Two" etc. (e.g. LabelOne, labelTwo ..).

**Necessary steps**

- Define constants `MEDSCOUNT` (=7 medications) and `CTLCOUNT` (=4 different control names)
- Define your Control name prefixes and counting strings in `UserForm_Initialize()`
- Use a helper procedure `ShowCtls` with a single parameter (number of medications)

**Main Code**

```
Option Explicit                  ' declaration head of code module

Const MEDSCOUNT As Integer = 7   ' define maximum number of medications           = 7
Const CTLCOUNT  As Integer = 4   ' define number of control names (prefixes only) = 4
Dim aCnt(), aCtl()               ' declare Counter strings and Control name prefixes

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
' Define your Counter strings and Control name prefixes
' (Note: first item with index 0 is a DUMMY in both cases)
  aCnt = Array("ZERO", "One", "Two", "Three", "Four", "Five", "Six", "Seven")
  aCtl = Array("DUMMY", "label", "MName", "MDose", "MFrequency")
End Sub

Private Sub Meds_Change()
' .. just to be on the safe side
  If Meds.value > MEDSCOUNT Then Meds.value = MEDSCOUNT
  If Meds.value < 1 Then Meds.value = 1
' show number of medications
  meds_txt.text = Meds.value
End Sub

Private Sub meds_txt_Change()
' call HELPER procedure with number of necessary medications (>> see below)
  ShowCtls Me.meds_txt.value
End Sub
```

**Helper procedure called by meds_txt_Change()**

```
Private Sub ShowCtls(nMeds As Integer)
  Dim i As Integer, ii As Integer
' hide fields greater than number of medications
   For i = 2 To MEDSCOUNT  ' NOTE: number 1 remains visible anyway
       For ii = 1 To CTLCOUNT
          Me.Controls(aCtl(ii) & aCnt(i)).Visible = IIf(i > nMeds, False, True)
       Next ii
   Next i
End Sub
```

**Hint**

You can easily adapt the naming logic by changing the `UserForm_Initialize()` event only (and of course the actual controls' names).

Answer (score 0):

ShowOne has 0 properties set to True, ShowTwo has 4, ShowThree has 8 etc. - you can see it is (0, 4, 8, 12, 16, 20, 24). So you can write a single function which takes this number as an argument and then sets the properties accordingly. 
Note that the properties are related - e.g. if

```
    labelTwo.Visible = True
```

Than

```
    MNameTwo.Visible
    MDoseTwo.Visible 
    MFrequencyTwo.Visible
```

are also True. So you can set these 4 to x, next 4 to y etc. Than you just pass (x,y,z,...) as function arguments.